# Flask Socket and Socket IO on android studio

Tags: android, flask-socketio

Hi i'm doing a small project on flask and socket IO but my android app seems to have some issue connecting.

Flask Server
[flask 2.2.2, flask Socket IO 5.3.6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ej6Td.png)

Android Studio Code
[implementation ('io.socket:socket.io-client:2.1.0')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEXvD.png)
[Button to emit"Function1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vH6Lz.png)

Im running the flask server on my PC and using an android phone to do debugging
Both are connected to the same Wifi
When the app starts up, nothing is displayed on the server, so does the button press.
How can i rectify this?

I expect the flask server on my PC to listen to the Function1 being emitted by my android studio